# Configure WYGWAM to use fonts from Typekit?

Tags: add-on, css, wygwam

[image]

I use custom CSS for WYGWAM fields.

I can use @font-face, but what if I want to use fonts via Typekit, is there a way to pull them in?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also swap to the very similar addon [Wyvern](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wyvern/), by BoldMinded, which has Typekit and Google Fonts support built in via the settings screen.

Answer (score 14):

There is a [one year old thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/typekit_fonts_in_wygwam_frame_injecting_scripts_into_iframe) on Pixel&Tonic’s support forum.

To use Typekit with Wygwam/CKEditor you have to include two scripts in your `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/XXXXXXXX.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

[Scott Wise figured out this hack](https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/typekit_fonts_in_wygwam_frame_injecting_scripts_into_iframe):

> I figured out a rough injection for the time being. In
>   `/themes/third_party/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`, on line 9 there is an
>   array push into the header that defines the CSS (presumably whatever
>   is defined in the `contentsCss` property):
>
> `h.push('');`
>
> I simply added another push() immediately following that (with both
>   scripts I need in one string), and now I've got my scripts into each
>   instance of the iFrame, fully functional!

---

**Update:** It seems that ckeditor.js (Wygwam 2.6.3) has changed since the [forum thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/typekit_fonts_in_wygwam_frame_injecting_scripts_into_iframe).

You can try this:

In ckeditor.js replace

```
else k.push('<link type="text/css" rel=stylesheet href="'+j+'">');
```

with

```
else k.push('<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/XXXXXXXX.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script><link type="text/css" rel=stylesheet href="'+j+'">');
```

(XXXXXXXX = the string from your Typekit embed code)

Comment: | Thanks - it's not clear quite where to place that - the ckeditor.js file is compressed - or how.

Comment: I updated my answer for the current Wygwam. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me - have you gotten it to cooperate? I wonder if the problem is I'm calling the script from a dev domain, not the final one.

Comment: Have you added the dev domain to your Typekit configuration?

Comment: I tried this as well and got a console error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`. The domain is in the TypeKit configuration. I wonder if it has to do with how Wygwam loads the scripts?

Comment: I would be surprised if a hack like this would work reliably. When I was adding Typekit support to Wyvern this sort of approach did not work. I spent more than 40 hours trying to get this to work, and the final solution was more involved than this. If memory serves me correctly it has something to do with a cross-domain request from within an iframe that is rendered to the page via JS.

Comment: This doesn't work as ckeditor.js is compressed

Comment: This technique has served me well but now in Safari 8 (on OSX 10.10 Yosemite) a 403 Forbidden error is thrown when ckeditor is loaded. The font displays fine on the website so I know it's not a whitelisting issue. It works fine in other browsers. Any ideas??

Comment: Same here - fails in Safari. Anyone find a work around for that?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of modifying CK Editor files which would likely get nuked if you update the add on you are best to make a `customConfig` in the **Editor Configurations**.

Change this and save this out to where you keep your front-end templates.

```
var typkitID = 'XXXXXX';

CKEDITOR.on(
   'instanceReady',
   function(ev) {
      var $script = document.createElement('script'),
         $editor_instance = CKEDITOR.instances[ev.editor.name];

      $script.src = '//use.typekit.com/'+typkitID+'.js';
      $script.onload = function() {
         try{$editor_instance.window.$.Typekit.load();}catch(e){}
      };

      $editor_instance.document.getHead().$.appendChild($script);
   }
);
```

Then in the editor `Modules > WygwamEditor > Configurations > CONFIG-NAME`

[image: Change custom Config to use out typekit config.]

You will also need to point the editor to your CSS file and likely use a `bodyClass`.

Comment: 3 years on, in case this is useful to anyone else, I could only get this to work by changing the last line injecting into head to: $editor_instance.document.appendStyleSheet($script.src);